# Is there a build process template for TFS 2015?

Tags: build, migration, build-process, tfs-2015, build-process-template

Usually every new major version of Team Foundation Server comes with a new version of a default XAML build process template.

I'm well aware of the new build vNext system introduced in TFS 2015, but regarding the legacy one - is there a new build process template for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, TFS2015 uses the same version of build process template as TFS2013. The Default Template is TfvcTemplate.12.xaml